# Button for form working when running locally but not in vitest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

Can't click on a button nested in a form using vitest and react testing library

When I run the application locally I see the button working fine (firing a console log when I click). When I try to test user interaction with the button it's not triggering.

**Button**

```
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <button
            type="submit"
            aria-label="submitContract"
            className="someClass">
            buttonName
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
```

**Test with different variations of firing the click event**

```
test("Form", async () => {
  render(<Form />);

  await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "submitContract" }));
  await screen.getByText("buttonName").click();
  await user.click(screen.getByText("buttonName"));
});
```

I have got it working when taking the button out of the form (and removing the handleSubmit from the form) and changing the type. E.G

```
         <button
            type="button"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            aria-label="submitContract"
            className="someClass">
            buttonName
          </button>
```

but this feels like bad practice. On click is generic. On submit is more informative for this use case.

It's odd. I've done this before and had no problems. Only difference is I'm now using vitest instead of jest and happy-dom.

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-pdf": "^6.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "happy-dom": "^7.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.4",
    "vitest": "^0.24.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^6.2.2"
  }
}
```

Further example of it not working in a test (failing to trigger the console log)

```
export const Foo = () => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log("fired");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <button aria-label="test" type={"submit"}>x</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

```
import { test } from "vitest";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Foo } from "./Foo";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

const user = userEvent.setup();

test("Foo", async () => {
  render(<Foo />);

  await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "test" }));
  await user.click(screen.getByText("x"));
});
```

Comment: https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/react-testing-library/functions/react-testing-library.fireEvent.submit

Comment: Works! Thanks. But I'm baffled. 

Is this a change in react testing library? I have an example I can see right now where the test just uses user.click on a nested form button and it works. Doesn't use act and doesn't use the submit on the fireevent.

Perhaps this is because I'm using happy-dom?